# Not able to reference Image source with relative path in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a ClassLibrary project, and added a xaml of Window type.
I wrote a console application and showing this wpf window.

The problem is I have to show an Icon in this window.

If I am using following code it is not working

```
<Image Source="../Images/Folder-icon.png"></Image>
```

When I give some hard coded path like

```
<Image Source="E:\MyApp\Images\Folder-icon.png"></Image>
```

it works.

Why I have to give an hard coded path value? Is there any solution?

Hope I gave enough information. Please help I am struggling with this problem for more that 2 hours.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If Images folder is added in same project of its usage, this should work for you:

```
<Image Source="/Images/Folder-icon.png"/>
```

---

Or use [**Pack Uri**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) specifically:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/Folder-icon.png"/>
```

---

In case image resides in different project than current project where your XAML resides, you have to use more verbose definition of Pack URI where you have to specify the assembly name where image is added.

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Assembly;component/Images/Folder-icon.png"/>
```

Replace *Assembly* with actual assembly name where image is added into.

---

Also make sure **`Build Action`** is set to **`Resource`** for file *Folder-icon.png*.

---

**UPDATE**:

More verbose definition of Pack URI works in sample as well. Try this out:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1;component/Folder-icon.png"/>
```

Comment: Build Action is set to Resource for image file?

Comment: I can send sample application if you can help me

Comment: Can you try this out in fresh application and see if that works out because it works definitely with all above points.

Comment: I have tried with the fresh application, if you want I can send you

Comment: Sure, share your application.

Comment: Upload it somewhere over Git, skydrive, dropbox etc. Also, you can update your question with relevant code if it's too small.

Comment: Did you also make sure that the image file is a folder named `Images` in your Visual Studio project? Otherwise the Pack URI would be `pack://application:,,,/Assembly;component/Folder-icon.png`

Comment: Yes, also in the sample application I tried without any folder name.
It is killing me couldn't solve it :(

Comment: Post project structure in your question (snapshot of it would suffice).

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=1620A8D4FF9B2AF2&id=1620A8D4FF9B2AF2%21111  Added the code here, let me know if you can access, cause I never tried

Comment: This works for me in your sample - `<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1;component/Folder-icon.png"/>`.

Comment: Oh.. the pack combination I didn't try with the Build action set to resource. Sorry, but thank you very much

Comment: @user3013076 Go to the rebuild menu select clean or rebuild.

Comment: <Image Source="/Images/Folder-icon.png"/> doesn't work

Answer (score 20):

Answers to such questions are often confusing because the principles/prerequisites for the solution to work are not explained correctly. This is the case with the currently selected answer too. So it's a good thing to be aware of:

- The different ways to manage and reference a file/resource added to the project.
- How to specify in the markup the URL for a file managed as `Content`.
- The non-required use of the pack URI instead of the simple URL

---

Things to consider:

**1. How to declare the type of file/resource you are adding to your project.**

This is done by adding appropriate folder and files to the project using the Solution Explorer in VS, e.g. in a subfolder `Images`:

[image]

and specifying properties for each added file (on the right side below):

[image]

The `Build Action` is set to `Content` and the `Copy To Output Directory` is set to `Copy if newer`. This is how files should be added when you don't want them to be embedded into the assembly.

- For reference, the Content option is one of the possible options to access a file in WPF. Other options include Resource (either embedded in the current assembly, or in another assembly of the same application) and Site of Origin to access a file which has no relationship with the current application:

  [image]
  <sup>[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf)</sup>

Content type files are linked to the executable (assembly) only by the relative path they are stored. The relative URL is stored in assembly metadata. These files are expected to be found at execution time, but they can be changed/updated without recompiling the assembly.

The Copy if Newer value means the compiler will take care of copying the original file to the right place during the assembly building process, so that the relative path is preserved, e.g. if a file is located in the subfolder `Images` of the project, e.g. `MyProject/Images` then a copy will be created in `MyProject/bin/Debug/Images` when the application is compiled in debug mode. The assembly being built in `MyProject/bin/Debug`, the relative path is the same.

**2. How to specify a Content file URL in the markup.**

This is the easy part, and usually the only one explained. But it works only if the previous step has been done correctly.

To use a content file, just use the markup shortcut of the relative path (relative to the assembly): `<Image Source="Images/Lighthouse.jpg"/>` (there is no leading `/`).

Other cases, where the file is not declared as Content type (e.g. an image which must be embedded into the assembly as a Resource, or a file which must be loaded from the network) involve syntax variations with the simple URL replaced by a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

**3. Non-required / excessive use of the pack URI.**

As the URI scheme can be used to reference anything, the pack URI solution is [often proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1444699/774575) to also reference files declared as `Content`. For our example, the equivalent pack URI would be: `pack://application:,,,/Images/Lighthouse.jpg` (note the leading `/`).

However the URL shortcut is more appropriate, and less error-prone for a standalone file which location relative to the assembly is known at design time.

For a more detailed view see:

[WPF Application Resource, Content, and Data Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/wpf-application-resource-content-and-data-files)

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by:

1. Name of my WPF User Control project: WpfControls
2. Name of the folder containing the image: Images
3. Name of the imgae file: Asdf.png
4. Include the folder and image file into the WpfControls project
5. The image file's *Build Action* set to *Resource*
6. The *Source* property in the Image tag set to:

   **<Image Source=/WpfControls;Component/Images/Asdf.png" />**